# CI Select SUM on two different conditions across 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
Table 1
+------+----------+
| tPID | location |
+------+----------+
|    1 |       1  |
|    2 |       2  |
+------+----------+

Table 2
+-------+------+---------+-----+-----+
| tdPID | tPID | Product |  IN | OUT |
+-------+------+---------+-----+-----+
|     1 |    1 |     1   |   8 |   0 |
|     2 |    1 |     2   |   5 |   0 |
|     3 |    2 |     3   |   0 |   3 |
|     4 |    2 |     2   |   0 |   2 |
+-------+------+---------+-----+-----+

// My query so far, this only return total of in - out in location 1, how do i get the sum in location 2 as a result together ?
$this->db->select(SUM(IN - OUT) as total_1);
$this->db->join('table1 b', 'a.tPID = b.tPID');
$this->db->where('b.location', '1');
$this->db->group_by('b.product');
$query = $this->db->get('table2 a');
$result = $query->result();
```

I have these 2 tables above, now I want to query the sum total of in and out of each product in table 2 according to the location in table 1 in one query. And I want my result to be grouped by the product, so to sum up I want to get the sum of in-out of each product according to the location.

```
// Expected result
array(
    array(
        [product] => 1
        [total_at_location_1] = 8
        [total_at_location_2] = 0
    ),
    array(
        [product] => 2
        [total_at_location_1] = 5
        [total_at_location_2] = -2
    ),
    array(
        [product] => 3
        [total_at_location_1] = 0
        [total_at_location_2] = -3
    )
);
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
$this->db->where('b.location', '1');
```

with this

```
$this->db->groupBy('tPID');
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention, I want my result to be grouped by the product by the way. so to sum up I want the total of in-out of each product at each location

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(IN-OUT),b.location from table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.tPID=b.tPID
GROUP BY b.location
```